# No link presented for creating a new tag wiki

Tags: bug, tags, tag-wiki

I am trying to create a wiki for this tag: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hyperdrive/info but the page has no link for creating it.

According to the text I should be able to add something that is then peer reviewed:

[image]

Not sure if this is indeed a bug, or just a privilege issue, but the page is unclear to me and I couldn't find help elsewhere.

Behavior experienced on Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 54.0

[**UPDATE** After it seemed solved after reload (see comment below) the issue is now back on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/hypercore/info and reloading does not do the trick.]

Comment: There is only one wiki for one tag

Comment: Can't I create it, if it does not yet exist? I just want to add a description (not create a new wiki per se)

Comment: This tag is used on only two questions, both of which are of dubious topicality. Are you *sure* it needs a wiki?

Comment: may be it has something to do with reputation i can see the link https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWPqm.png

Comment: @CodyGray sorry but i think you are missing the point, the point is that why he is not seeing the link to create tag wiki ( which i can)

Comment: I got the point, @Null, that's why I left a comment instead of an answer. It is no surprise you see the button; you have more than 20k reputation, so you have full tag wiki editing privileges. Arnold has to suggest an edit. Now, he's right, he should be able to do that. As the text says, any registered user can suggest edits to tag wikis subject to review by other community members, so there is certainly something fishy going on here.

Comment: Drag and Drop ! What do your Low Rep eyes see? http://imgur.com/a/qqYTF

Comment: perhaps there is unsolved bug with [tag-wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bug%20tag-wiki?mode=all), i hardly see status-complete  in previously reported bugs

Comment: no repro, 21 rep, using IE http://i.stack.imgur.com/FGoWu.png, now we need Will to check on Win 95.

Comment: Guys, I just reloaded and the 'Propose Tag Info' is now displayed! BTW It was on Ubuntu 16.04 with Firefox 54.0

Comment: This is closed as unreproducable, but I still have this error, now on a different tag info page (see question update).

Comment: Also no button to update existing tag infos, like https://stackoverflow.com/tags/event-sourcing/info Not sure if there are restrictions on that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Tag wiki edit suggestions are still limited in the same way as regular suggested edits are - you can only have 5 pending at a time, [among other reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81681/why-is-the-edit-button-disabled). Since you already had 5 pending suggested edits when you viewed the page, you weren't eligible to make an edit to the tag wiki.

Tag wikis never got some of the updates that the normal edit link on posts have gotten, so if you're not eligible the current functionality is that the button just disappears completely. A good feature request would be to update that to still display the button and show an error the same way regular edit links do. But not being able to suggest an edit is still by-design.

Comment: Thanks! Though it is *super confusing* that UI just disappears, it must be the 5 pending edits in my case. I was not aware that my tag edits yielded 2 pending requests: one for the tag wiki, and one for the tag wiki excerpt. I still have the 5 pending today...have to be patient ;)

Comment: BTW don't know if a tag info reviewer must be a tag creator / owner. But if that is the case I am dependent on one person to 'clear my stack' and if that takes long I'll be forced to delete my improvements to continue working elsewhere on SO.

Comment: The requirements to approve tag wiki edits are higher (you need 5,000 reputation instead of the usual 2,000) but that is the only requirement. Also, you can't retract a suggested edit once it's been submitted.

Comment: Thanks @animuson it is a 'handle-with-care' operation for someone to improve tag wiki's. Some warning could be in place..