# Is the current way of creating a new tag wiki intended?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I wanted to add a description to a tag and searched for a way to do it. I found a description of the content of a tag wiki, e.g. [What is a tag wiki? How do I write a good one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214337/what-is-a-tag-wiki-how-do-i-write-a-good-one), and also an explanation on how to edit a tag wiki ([How to tag wiki edit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382297/how-to-tag-wiki-edit)).
However, as in the 19-times upvoted comment below [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382298), I could not see the `improve tag info`, if currently no tag wiki is present:

> [image: tag with existing tag wiki]

compared to

> [image: tag without info]

I also found a similar issue in these questions: [No link presented for creating a new tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354623/no-link-presented-for-creating-a-new-tag-wiki) or [Improve Tag Info button does not indicate you have too many pending edits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413326/improve-tag-info-button-does-not-indicate-you-have-too-many-pending-edits), but I'm pretty sure that I currently don't have more than 5 edits pending.

The only way I found to create a new tag wiki is from the tags search and then pressing edit, which I found very non intuitive and only found after searching for a while.

> [image: tag search with option to edit]

Since I've spend some time writing this question, I'm now even more confused. Now it states a different description, which even asks to create a wiki:

> [image: tag without wiki and option to create one]

I'll assume that for the first screenshot the edit queue was full, which caused that no "can you help us create it?" message was shown and now for the second screenshot, the queue was not full.

Is this behaviour of hiding the creation option (temporarily) at one place, while still allowing the edit via another way intended?

Comment: When you lay it out like this, this design is clearly wildly unintuitive. Another way to create a wiki for a tag without one is to click [the "Learn more..." link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VM1r.png), and then [the button at the bottom of that page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM7IK.png).

Comment: Your assumption is correct: the "help us create it" bit is only appended if you are currently allowed to edit. That means if you don't have full wiki editing privileges, it falls on whether you are currently able to suggest an edit. That could be for several reasons: you have too many edits pending already, the queue is full, or you are currently banned from suggesting edits.

Comment: @zcoop98 Except that wouldn't solve this particular problem, because that button also completely disappears if you cannot currently edit the wiki, as mentioned above. Tag wiki controls are very outdated and don't follow our "don't just remove buttons completely" philosophy. In summary, if the "help us create it" link disappears, so does the edit button on that page.

Comment: @animuson Agreed; I didn't intend offer that as a solution as much as just another way to get to the editor. The UX is really rough here; that disappearing editor button on its own has caused confusion and complaints for a very, very long time.

Comment: Yep, I had already "reported" that strange (changing) "Behaviour" in the Comments for the [Improve Tag Info button does not indicate...] Thread (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/413326/3799241) + cumbersome Navig/Workflow + Tag Wiki nearly impossible to find for Askers... Pity Staff didn't notice/participate in that Thread from a few weeks ago...