# No "Improve Tag Info" button for empty tags

Tags: discussion

I noticed for the [slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/slideshow) tag that it had no usage excerpt or wiki written for it.

I decided to add a wiki for this post, but I saw there wasn't any button to do so on the initial question page that clicking a tag will take you to:

[image: Question page for tag]

If you click the "Learn more..." button it takes you to the *About* page like usual:

[image: About page for tag]

I assume since the tag is empty, the "Improve tag info" button is hidden as there is nothing to improve. The excerpt/wiki needs to be created before being improved.

However, the same logic can be applied to why the "Learn more..." button should be hidden. If there is no excerpt/wiki for a tag, clicking the "Learn more..." button doesn't actually teach you anything. It leads you into entering an empty wiki.

I think for cases where a tag doesn't have any excerpt/wiki, both the "Improve tag info" and "Learn more..." buttons should be hidden, and instead replaced with an "Edit tag info" or "Create tag info" button.

Comment: This might be a [feature-request]/[support] question more than a [discussion]. Though I do think the intention is that you would click the "The [tag:slideshow] tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/15103)?" link instead of the "Learn more…" button.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the current way of creating a new tag wiki intended?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415065/is-the-current-way-of-creating-a-new-tag-wiki-intended)

Comment: You have to create tag info before you can improve it. So it makes sense in a very literal way that it does not display. Also related, IIRC the link to "help us add a description" only shows up if the suggested edit review queue is not full (for <20k users).

Answer (score -2):

Once you click on <kbd>Create tag info</kbd> button

[image: create_tag_info]

You will be redirected to the *Editing tag info* page where you can save your edits clicking on the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button

[image: save_edits]