# How can I propose a new tag wiki?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I've created a new tag, [discosweb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discosweb), which is for questions revolving around [ESA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Space_Agency)'s DISCOSweb API.

I want to create a tag wiki for it, but I can't see any such  option.

What am I missing?

[image: About page]

[image: Questions tagged page]

Comment: The circumstanses of the "help us create..." prompt are a bit... convoluted. You can use the link directly: https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/157661 (pro tip: open a post, enter edit mode, and click/hover on the tag name - the link to editing the tag wiki/excerpt will be there)

Comment: Hmm, I can see [the "help us create it" link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emlqL.png) on the question page.

Comment: Thanks @OlegValteriswithUkraine

Is this a bug then? Surely if I can do it with the direct link, I should be able to see that option

Comment: It looks like you have worked out how to edit the tag since, as there is now a pending edit.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater eh, not quite - I do not remember the exact algorithm, but the prompt is shown conditionally (f.e., it is shown to Andrew T., but not for me and you). I'll try to dig out the meta Q&A describing the process. Frankly, I don't like how the system is set up myself.

Comment: Seems odd at the very least...

Comment: @Larnu - I had to use the direct link provided by oleg

Comment: Ah, I found [the company's explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415065/is-the-current-way-of-creating-a-new-tag-wiki-intended#comment887684_415065) as to what the conditions are.

Comment: So the likely candidate is that when you viewed the page, the edit queue was full; not an uncommon occurrence (there's currently 485 in the queue as I write this, so only 15 slots).

Comment: Would it not make sense from a UX perspective, to still show the link, but maybe grey it out with a message to that effect?

Comment: @ScottishTapWater absolutely - the company admitted several times that the removal of the link is not desirable. However, they also stated that the components used are very outdated, and knowing the usual timespan of updates taking place on the network, it's going to take another 6-8 years to fix.

Comment: Fair enough, at least you got me sorted for today, thanks for your advice! It really is a shame that they won't open source the site... We could fix a lot of these small issues for them. It's not like the site's technology is the bit that makes it valuable.

Comment: @ScottishTapWater NP :) I faced the same head-scratching dilemma quite a while ago before finding a way to edit them directly. Maybe it'll be worth for me to look into making a userscript that adds an unconditional button, have been thinking about it for a while.

Comment: The [accepted answer](/a/354670/15497888) includes a link to the [complete list of reasons why the link would not appear](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81701/1099857).