# I created a tag, but there is no link to edit its tag wiki

Tags: support, tag-wiki

I [created a new tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/kitchen-azurerm/info) when asking a question and wanted to provide guidance on its usage to prevent infrastructure-related questions under it, but there is no `Edit Tag Wiki` button. I thought maybe it's because I just created it, but I can't see the button on other tag wikis either.

I only have two pending tag wiki edits so I have not hit the maximum of five pending wiki edits.

Does this mean the edit queue is full? Or is something else going on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No link presented for creating a new tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354623/no-link-presented-for-creating-a-new-tag-wiki) Read: Yes, queue is full or you've got 5 edits pending (less likely)

Comment: Can you not see the [Create tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/156311) button?

Comment: There's a "Create tag info" button [for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9urRZ.png). Suggested edit queue looks to be sitting pretty close to full so it may be absent due to that and present for me since my edit would not go into the review queue.

Comment: There is no button for me, and both the people who _can_ see it have 20k+ :p

Comment: I'm not sure if that answers my question or not. I have suggested recent other tag wiki edits recently but I also received a mod message regarding those submissions indicating they were rejected (and why). How do I see my pending tag wiki edits?

Comment: You have some "[Help us edit this Tag Info](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/156311) when you hover over the Tag... :idea:

Comment: @BendertheGreatest You can see suggestions here: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=activity&sort=suggestions, although it will also include completed ones, not just pending.

Comment: Tag wiki edits are with all other suggestions. [All actions > suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Comment: @chivracq That link got me to the edit window, but I'm still not sure why the button isn't showing for me. I'm still unsure whether this is a duplicate of the proposed dupe until I can verify my pending wiki edits.

Comment: You have 2 pending edits.

Comment: @HenryEcker and RyanM Thanks, both of you confirmed I don't already have five pending edits so this does not appear to be a dupe of the proposed dupe.

Comment: While I still don't have an answer as to why the button was hidden (it does not help that there are several conditions that could cause this which are not relayed in the UI), I was able to submit a wiki edit for that tag using the edit link provided by @chivracq that displays in the tag modal dialog on a post.

Comment: + I also see the same Link on the '[Questions tagged `kitchen-azurerm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kitchen-azurerm)' Page with a "*The [tag:kitchen-azurerm] tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/156311)?*" Sentence, and the same Edit Link on the "*help us create it*" part...